# Google form notification script

Tags: google-apps-script

The notification script give title and value, and I am trying to get value only without title

Google Form script
**Method1**

```
var POST_URL = "hidden url";
    function onSubmit(e) {
      var response = e.response.getItemResponses();
      var items = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < response.length ; i++) {
        var question = response[i].getItem().getTitle();
        var answer = response[i].getResponse();
        var parts = answer.match(/[\s\S]{1,1024}/g) || [];

        if (answer == "") {continue;}
        for (var j = 0; j< parts.length; j++) {
          if (j == 0) {
            items.push({"name": question, "value": parts[j], "inline": true});
          } else {
          items.push({"name": question.concat(" (cont.)"), "value": parts[j], "inline": true});
          }
        }   
      }

      var options = {
        "method" : "post",
        "payload": JSON.stringify({
          "embeds": [
            {
              "title":"New request",
              "fields":items,
            }
          ]
        }
       )
      };

       UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_URL, options);
    };
```

**Method2 added**

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
    var fields = [];

    for (i = 0; i < e.response.getItemResponses().length; i++) {
        var response = e.response.getItemResponses()[i];
        fields.push({
            "name": response.getItem().getTitle(),
            "value": JSON.stringify(response.getResponse()),
            "inline": false
        });
    }

  var data = {
        "embeds": [{
            "title": "**Test Rep** — " + (e.source.getTitle() != null && e.source.getTitle().length > 0 ? e.source.getTitle() : "Untitled Form"),
            "type": "rich",
            "fields": fields,
        }]
    };

    var options = {
        method: "post",
        payload: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
    };

    Logger.log("Attempting to send:");
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("Hidden URL", options);
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
};
```

The method2 do same job as method1 but i hope someone can help to workaround

I expected to get notification with form title + the value of two fields without question title.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem**

A form has the title "New request" and has two questions.
The notification should have the form title "New request" and the answers to the questions but not the questions themselves.

**A solution**

Try these steps:

(1) Remove or comment out

```
var question = response[i].getItem().getTitle();
```

(2) Change this

```
items.push({"name": question, "value": parts[j], "inline": true});
```

to

```
items.push({"value": parts[j], "inline": true});
```

(3) Change this

```
  items.push({"name": question.concat(" (cont.)"), "value": parts[j], "inline": true});
```

to

```
  items.push({"value": parts[j], "inline": true});
```

Comment: Thx for reply, when I do this I got trigger error as follow:

Request failed for "I hide url" returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"embeds": ["0"]} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
    at onSubmit(Code:35)

Comment: Try removing the comma after _items_ in

"embeds": [
            {
              "title":"New request",
              "fields":items,
            }

Comment: Thx but still not work, when i remove question field it will give nothing, I posted 2nd method and hope someone can help